# RaspberryPi2EGLFS guide - EGL/GLES libraries fix fail

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, qt

I built Qt 5.12.3 for Raspberry Pi following the [RaspberryPi2EGLFS guide](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) from Qt Wiki.

I was able to reproduce almost each one of the steps described in the guide, but on **step 14** (EGL/GLES libraries fix), I failed to create some symbolic links.

I couldn't create the following links

```
sudo ln -s /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmEGL.so /opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so
sudo ln -s /opt/vc/lib/libbrcmGLESv2.so /opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so
```

because the files `/opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so` and `/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so` already exist.

So, I moved those files to `/opt/vc/lib/libEGL.so_backup` and `/opt/vc/lib/libGLESv2.so_backup`, then I created the symbolic links and the rest of the steps worked like a charm.

The problem is that my applications (running on EGLFS) are looking so ulgy that is hard to believe that everything is OK. Colors are not good, styles are not applied, text is bigger in some places, text is over icons in some other places, etc.

In addition to that, apps that run OK in another Qt build, are crashing on this one.

So, I think the problem may be those symbolic links. Are they correct? Am I missing something? Anybody here had the same problem with EGLFS? If yes, how did you fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Any tutorial which tells you to run rpi-update has got to be suspect.

Comment: You might try putting the actual files back in and removing the symlinks.

Comment: @goldilocks, I removed the symlinks, put the original files back and restarted the system. Then, when I try to run the application, the screen goes black and the terminal shows this message: "QOpenGLShaderProgram: could not create shader program
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
Could not link shader program:
 """

Comment: Qt is a big thing.  I think if there is any way for you to avoid compiling it you should.  Qt 5 is on Raspbian now, isn't it?  If it is about the versioning, I would even switch distros to one that has the version I want rather than bother with compiling it.  You know if you compile it once and depend on that, you are probably going to have to do it again later -- and all kinds of things can throw a wrench into the reproducibility of the process.